# Using flextable functions (eg merge_at, hline) in functions

Tags: r, flextable

I'm trying to style my flextables programatically, but I ran into problems when using certain functions, for example `merge_at()` and `hline()`; they only style the very last entry of the column I'm referencing, no matter what row I try to use.

Here is a minimal example. `iris_a` turns out to look like I want it to, while `iris_b` is changed in a way I can't comprehend.

```
# setup
library(tidyverse)
library(officer)
library(flextable)
thin_border <- fp_border(color = "gray")

setosa <- iris %>% group_split(Species) %>% .[[1]] %>% slice(1:2)
versicolor <- iris %>% group_split(Species) %>% .[[2]] %>% slice(1:2)

iris_a <- bind_rows(setosa, versicolor) %>% mutate(spec = case_when(
    Species == "setosa" ~ "set",
    Species == "versicolor" ~ "versi"
)) %>% flextable()
iris_b <- iris_a

specs <- c("setosa", "versicolor")

# actual transformation

for (k in specs) {
    iris_a<- iris_a%>% hline(., i = ~ Species == k, j = 1:5, border = thin_border)
}
for(k in specs){
    iris_a <- iris_a %>% merge_at(., i = ~ Species == k, j = ~spec)
}
iris_a %>% fix_border_issues()

# success, a nice table; now I wrap the loops into functions

merge_cells <- function(flex, location){
    for(k in location){
    flex <- flex %>% merge_at(., i = ~ Species == k, j = ~spec)    
    }
flex
}

add_vlines <- function(flex, location){
    for (k in location) {
        flex <- flex %>% hline(., i = ~ Species == k, j = 1:5, border = thin_border)
    }
flex
}

iris_b <- iris_b %>%
    add_vlines(., "set") %>%
    merge_cells(., "set")
iris_b %>% fix_border_issues()
```

It doesn't matter to what `location` is set, the outcome is the same (eg `location = specs`).

I also tried to tackle this issue with `mk_par()` but to no avail.

Where did I go wrong?

addendum: forgot to add, `location` can be set to *anything*, the outcome is still the same (`iris_b %>% merge_cells(., "something")`).

Comment: This is not valid: `iris_b %>% add_vlines(., "set") %>% iris_b %>% merge_cells(., "set")`. Maybe you can fix that and it will help?

Comment: @DavidGohel Thanks for chiming in! When cleaning up the code, I somehow screwed up a couple of things. Now the code runs, and actually shows the (unwanted) outcome as described in my post.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the issue and why not using `merge_v()`. when using `j = ~spec`, it means it will always operate on column `spec`, is that your issue?

Comment: @DavidGohel Unfortunately, I can't use `merge_v()` on a column which shows, eg, pvalues. These need to be merged at very specific locations. The issue: while a normal loop works perfectly, as soon as I wrap `merge_at()` into a function like `merge_cells()`, it only operates on the very last rows of the specified column. Passing `"setosa"`, `"versicolor"` or even `"whatever"`...only `"versi"` gets merged. The same holds for `hline()` . Here is the table `iris_b`:  https://imgur.com/a/a5WonNn

Comment: @DavidGohel ... I looked at the source code and found in both functions, `merge_at()` and `hline()`, the function `get_rows_id()` which starts with `if (is.null(i)) {i <- seq_len(maxrow)}`. If I were to guess, I'd say the culprit is burrowed there, but I haven't had the time to play around with it yet and lack the knowledge to guess why this should even be a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you fix your issue. Your formula is the issue. I reduced the example to a simpler case.

```
library(flextable)

dat <- structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 7, 6.4), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.2), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 4.7, 4.5), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 
0.2, 1.4, 1.5), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("setosa", 
"versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor"), spec = c("set", 
"set", "versi", "versi")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

merge_cells <- function(flex, location){
  for(k in location){
    form <- as.formula(paste0("~ spec %in% '", k, "'"))
    flex <- merge_at(flex, i = form, j = ~spec) 
  }
  flex
}

flextable(dat) |> merge_cells(location = "set")
```

[image]

Comment: Since I need to loop over `Species` to merge `spec`, I changed your code to `form <- as.formula(paste0("~ Species == '", k, "'"))`, which does exactly what I wanted; thank you so much!
For educational reasons, do you happen to know why I can't pass formulas explicitly? Is this due to scoping? I.e., does it get evaluated at the wrong time and thus turned into NULL?
PS: not enough reuputation for upvoting ;(

Comment: I don't know but it did not turned to null, but a vector of FALSE

Comment: when you create a formula I think (not sure, but it can be easily checked) variables are not understood as is, you could also do the operation with rlang but I think that formula for this is simpler

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time with this, I learned a lot!